# Trigger to update value with no of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

trying to set up a trigger but struggling to it to work the way i want, i want to update a field oppo_pono with the no of opportunity records created for a particular company record
so 1 company can have multiple opportunities and i want to record the no of master opportunities created for a company, so the first master opp created for a company would be set to 1 and so on

ive set the trigger up below but its setting the oppo_pono with the count from all companies rather then the one i am creating the opportunity for

my trigger below

```
USE [CRM]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[GeneratePNo]    Script Date: 1/7/2021 3:55:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[GeneratePNo]
ON [dbo].[Opportunity]
FOR insert
AS 

declare @OppPrimary Int
declare @company Int
declare @compid Int
declare @type nvarchar(40)
declare @childopp nchar(1)
declare @pono int

Select  @OppPrimary = Oppo_OpportunityId,
        @company = Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId,
        @compid = comp_companyid,
        @type = Oppo_Type,
        @childopp = oppo_childoppo,
        @pono = oppo_pono
FROM Inserted inner join company on Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId = @compid


Begin
    UPDATE [Opportunity] SET oppo_pono = (select count(*) from vSearchListOpportunity where Oppo_Deleted is null and @type = 'Master' and Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId = ) +1
WHERE Oppo_OpportunityId =@OppPrimary 

End
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: And what happens when an opportunity is deleted? Do you then renumber all of the others as well?

Comment: wont really be deleting any master opportunities as they will have child opportunities linked to them

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you have not taken into account the `inserted` pseudo-table having multiple rows. You also have a number of outright syntax errors.

**EDIT:** *Following your comments I think I understand what you are trying to do. My original solution will not work here because indexed view cannot have ranking functions, but I have modified it to work with what you need.*

Ideally, you wouldn't care about the actual IDs lining up, and just use an `IDENTITY` column, but often an ID series per group is needed.

Generally a view with correct indexing will be the more performant option, but it depends what you need.

---

### Using a View

I will show you a solution that can be used for a lot of different types of aggregations which normally require triggers. **This only works for your problem  if you intend to have the numbering change if a row gets deleted out the middle of the grouping. If you want the numbering to remain then use a trigger instead**

I am unsure the exact relation of `Opportunity`, `Company` and `vSearchListOpportunity` (seems to be a view on `Opportunity`) but you should be able to modify this to suit.

Create an indexed view on the data, and include a row number for each row:

```sql
CREATE VIEW vOpportunityNumbered
AS
SELECT
    o.Oppo_OpportunityId,
    o.Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId,
    o.Oppo_Type,
    o.oppo_childoppo,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (PARTITION BY o.Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId ORDER BY o.Oppo_OpportunityId)
    -- Order by primary key to get deterministic ordering
FROM Opportunity AS o
WHERE o.Oppo_Deleted IS NULL;

GO
```

Now, to support this view, we cannot index it directly, as mentioned. We *can*, however, create an index on the base table that will support it:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX opp_CompanyOpportunity
    ON Opportunity  (Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId, Oppo_OpportunityId) 
    -- note the ordering of the columns
    INCLUDE (Oppo_Type, oppo_childoppo)
    WITH (OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = ON) -- ONLY FOR SQL2019
;

GO
```

This view will now give you a sequential row numbering of `Opportunity` for each distinct `Company`.

---

### Triggers

If you wish for the IDs to always remain the same no matter what happens to intervening rows, you will need a trigger (i.e. a deleted row will leave a gap in the numbers).

Every trigger has two tables, `inserted` and `deleted`, which contain the data that was changed. For update triggers, both tables have data, a row in each for each changed row.

This means that the trigger is executed **once** per statement, and these tables contain **all** the relevant rows. You cannot, however, update them directly; you must join the real tables to them.

So let's take a look at how to write a trigger. Again, I'm somewhat guessing as to the relations of the tables:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[GeneratePNo]
ON [dbo].[Opportunity]
AFTER INSERT  -- FOR is an alternative syntax, AFTER is more usual
AS 
-- No need for BEGIN and END, the whole batch until GO is the trigger
SET NOCOUNT ON;  -- Prevent DONE_IN_PROC rowcount messages

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted))
    RETURN;   -- Bail-out early if no rows

-- We do not declare variables because we cannot store multiple rows in variables

UPDATE
    o
SET oppo_pono =
    ISNULL(  --If there are no other rows we would get a null
    (SELECT MAX(allO.oppo_pono)
        FROM Opportunity allO
    -- no need for the following two filters as the oppo_pono needs to be unique anyway
    -- where allO.Oppo_Deleted is null and allO.type = 'Master'
        WHERE allO.Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId = inserted.Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId
    ), 0) + 1

FROM inserted i
JOIN Opportunity o ON o.Oppo_OpportunityId = i.Oppo_OpportunityId;
-- We join inserted table on primary key always

GO
```

There are more efficient ways to write that update, but it depends whether you are inserting a lot of rows. An `INSTEAD OF` trigger will also be more performant here, but I haven't attempted that as I don't have your table definition.

Comment: thanks for this - how would i go about auto incrementing this no? basically what i wanted to achieve was to create a field on the opp record (oppo_pono) which would auto increment each time a new master opp was created against a company (there is a dropdown list field on the opp table called oppo_type with an option called master) so a new master opp was created against a company and it was the first one the oppo_pono would be set to 01 then next master opp entered for the same company would be set to 02 - if a new master opp was created against a different company then it would be set to 01